# Is there a social/off-topic area related to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I just hit exactly 7000 points on Stack Overflow, which, to me, is really cool.

Is there any social/lounge/off-topic area related to Stack Overflow, specifically where one might go to commemorate such an occasion?

Comment: [meta-tag:chat]?

Answer (score 8):

[Chat!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/)

Pick your favorite site, click the *chat* link in the top bar, and pick a room. Meta is often more slackful, especially the [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).

Comment: That'll do, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's one of the things the [chat server](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) is good for.